# How do i find the right color combo for the transparent background color?

Tags: image, css, colors, background-color

See image:

[image]

The grayed out area is actually an image.

How do i find the closest colors to create a similar color using css3?

I find the following colors the closest but not sure if they are a match since I don't know how to use them in CSS3:

5A5757 - Top

585555 - Bottom

Comment: Try http://colorschemedesigner.com/

Answer (score 3):

**Put this code into your css and set height.**

```
background: #5a5757; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5a5757 0%, #5a5757 15%, #2b4244 15%, #2b4244 31%, #585555 31%, #585555 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#5a5757), color-stop(15%,#5a5757), color-stop(15%,#2b4244), color-stop(31%,#2b4244), color-stop(31%,#585555), color-stop(100%,#585555)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5a5757 0%,#5a5757 15%,#2b4244 15%,#2b4244 31%,#585555 31%,#585555 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5a5757 0%,#5a5757 15%,#2b4244 15%,#2b4244 31%,#585555 31%,#585555 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5a5757 0%,#5a5757 15%,#2b4244 15%,#2b4244 31%,#585555 31%,#585555 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5a5757 0%,#5a5757 15%,#2b4244 15%,#2b4244 31%,#585555 31%,#585555 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#5a5757', endColorstr='#585555',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Comment: Thanks.  This looks about right.  ONly thing is that I don't need that green strip and how do I add opacity? I don't want to use opacity property maybe rgba is a better solution?

Comment: You have to use opacity because rgba() will not work for these code.Because we already set gradient as a background color.